# Gaussian crash while calculating vibrational frequencies for an organic molecule

Tags: gaussian

I'm trying to run an opt+ freq calculation using B3LYP/Lanl2DZ for an organic molecule that contains 4 $\ce{CF3}$ groups, my gaussian suddenly crashed, so I did the calculation in two steps: first opt then freq. I noticed that my Gaussian stopped in the second step "freq" so I supposed that my geometry is optimized.

I want to know how can I fix this issue in order to get the vibrations too.

Here is where my gaussian crashed and no error is displayed:

```
     **** Warning!!: The largest alpha MO coefficient is  0.11043379D+02

   1 Symmetry operations used in ECPInt.
 ECPInt:  NShTT=   20100 NPrTT=  168365 LenC2=   14854 LenP2D=   62313.
 LDataN:  DoStor=T MaxTD1= 4 Len=   56
 Symmetrizing basis deriv contribution to polar:
 IMax=3 JMax=2 DiffMx= 0.00D+00
 G2DrvN: will do    46 centers at a time, making    1 passes.
 Calling FoFCou, ICntrl=  3107 FMM=F I1Cent=   0 AccDes= 0.00D+00.
 NEqPCM:  Using equilibrium solvation (IEInf=0, Eps=   8.9300, EpsInf=   2.0283)
 G2PCM: DoFxE=T DoFxN=T DoGrad=T DoDP/DQ/DG/TGxP=FFFF NFrqRd=   0 IEInf=0 SqF1=F DoCFld=F IF1Alg=4.
 End of G2Drv F.D. properties file   721 does not exist.
 End of G2Drv F.D. properties file   722 does not exist.
 End of G2Drv F.D. properties file   788 does not exist.
          IDoAtm=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
 NEqPCM:  Using equilibrium solvation (IEInf=0, Eps=   8.9300, EpsInf=   2.0283)
          Differentiating once with respect to electric field.
                with respect to dipole field.
          Differentiating once with respect to nuclear coordinates.
 Keep R1 ints in memory in canonical form, NReq=1869758414
```

.

Comment: Is there any output to stderr?

Comment: stderr?????????

Comment: How much memory did you have available/allocate to this calculation?

Comment: @AIme999 wzkchem5 is referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams. The Gaussian program can return certain errors, but its possible the issue was from the computer you submitted on. wzkchem was asking if any computer errors were logged.

Comment: %mem=16GB with 8 cores the maximum of cores and memory of my computer  @Hayden S , thank you Tyberius  for the clarification

Comment: I didnt notice any error o the output file there was only what I shared above @wzkchem5

Comment: Depending on the script or command that you use to submit the Gaussian job, the stderr may have been directed to somewhere else. The stderr message may have been output to the screen, to another file, or lost altogether.

Comment: I've also seen "mysterious" ends when the calculation is killed by a cluster running out of time (e.g., you set the job to run for 4 days .. time is up).

Comment: Without more information, it looks like you won't be getting an answer. I'm voting to close, especially because of your first comment.